# Is there a size() member function for std::pair?

Tags: c++, hash, std-pair

I was following a hash table implementation tutorial and came across this:

```
class HashTable {
private:
    static const int hashGroups = 10;
    std::list<std::pair<int,std::string>> table[hashGroups];
```

```
bool HashTable::isEmpty() const {
    int sum{};
    for(int i{}; i < hashGroups; i++) {
        sum += table[i].size();
    }
    
    if(!sum) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the isEmpty() member function, why is table[i].size() valid? In my interpretation, table is a list of pairs, therefore, table[i] should return a pair at index [i]. However, there are no member function size() in std::pair.

Comment: It's easy enough to focus on `std::list<std::pair<int,std::string>>` - that's a scary lot of punctuation for someone learning the language, but another point where you might have realised what you'd done was when you thought *"`table[i]` should return a pair at `index [i]`"* - because list data structures aren't randomly indexable, the Standard Library doesn't provide an `operator[](size_t)` member for `std::list` - that would almost be encouraging beginners to write horribly inefficient code.  A good place to check such things is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Answer (score 8):

`table` is an array of `std::list` of `std::pair`, so `table[i]` is a `std::list` and it has [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size) function.